# (nvme0n1p1): re-mounted. Opts: errors=remount-ro

Tags: boot, 16.04, partitioning, mount

```
$ dmesg | grep nvme
[    1.017031]  nvme0n1: p1 p2 p3 p4
[    7.487584] EXT4-fs (nvme0n1p1): mounted filesystem with ordered data mode. Opts: (null)
[    7.624166] EXT4-fs (nvme0n1p1): re-mounted. Opts: errors=remount-ro
[    8.472627] EXT4-fs (nvme0n1p2): mounted filesystem with ordered data mode. Opts: (null)
[    8.475500] EXT4-fs (nvme0n1p3): mounted filesystem with ordered data mode. Opts: (null)
```

1. What does the `re-mounted. Opts: errors=remount-ro` mean?
2. What kind of corrective measures are required to solve this error?

Note: nvme0n1p1 is a logical partition that hosts /.

**/etc/fstab**

```
# <file system> <mount point>   <type>  <options>       <dump>  <pass>
# / was on /dev/nvme0n1p1 during installation
UUID=xxx        /               ext4    errors=remount-ro 0       1
# /home was on /dev/nvme0n1p3 during installation
UUID=yyy       /home            ext4    defaults          0       2
# /usr/local was on /dev/nvme0n1p2 during installation
UUID=zzz      /usr/local        ext4    defaults          0       2
# swap was on /dev/nvme0n1p4 during installation
#UUID=rrrr    none              swap    sw                0       0
/dev/mapper/cryptswap1 none swap sw 0 0
```

Comment: please provide your fstab.. `/etc/fstab`

Comment: @Leroy_Brown I have provided fstab w/o the UUID info

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mount options can generally be found documented in the mount(8) manpage, try "man mount" or this URL:
http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/man8/mount.8.html

> **errors={continue|remount-ro|panic}** Define the behavior when an error is encountered. (Either ignore errors and just mark the
>   filesystem erroneous and continue, or remount the filesystem
>   read-only, or panic and halt the system.) The default is set in the
>   filesystem superblock, and can be changed using tune2fs(8).